# Custom ContextManager for DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

I created a contextmanager in Python 3 to modify and manage a Pandas' DataFrame.

I have three functions, delete, update and insert.

So my question is this, how can I pass back the results of the dataframe back to the user outside the with statement?

```

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

with Editor(df) as editor:
    for idx, row in editor:
        row['COLUMN'] = "RANDOM VALUE"
        editor.update(idx, row)

df['COLUMN'] # still has original values
```

```

How do I get my updated values back from the ContextManager?

Comment: If you don't want to use editor object data, why are you creating its object at first place? How about static or module delete, update and insert methods and loop over df itself? No need for context manager either.

Answer (score 0):

Your context manager probably looks something like this:

```
class Editor():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.df

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

    def update(self):
        pass
```

So get the modified object you could do something like 
`df = editor.df` right after the for-loop is complete.

Not sure what benefit you are getting out of the context manager though.